How can I dynamically handle a call on Twilio in real time and with Python?
I'm building an app that does the following:

Make an outbound call.
Start streaming when the callee picks it up
Transcribe the stream in real time with Vosk
Detect a keyword to tell apart two different automated responses
Once the right automated response is identified, transfer the call to my personal number

I'm having trouble with point 5. I don't know how to dial my own number in an ongoing call.
I would have to use the verb <Dial> conditionally, and afaik, that's not possible.
For context, I'm using Twilio functions, a Flask server with websockets support, and ngrok to connect localhost to Twilio. Here's my code.
The first module contains the logic to send requests to Twilio:
from twilio.rest import Client
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse, Start
from twilio.request_validator import RequestValidator
from server import file_path
import os
import requests
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

# Global variables
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
# Functions
call_test_url = "https://my_function_url.com"
# Security
validator = RequestValidator(auth_token)

def call_request():
# We read ngrok public URL from a file
  if os.path.exists(file_path):
    with open(file_path, "r") as file:
          public_url = file.read().strip()

    stream_url = public_url.replace("https", "wss") + "/stream"
# Util that dynamically generates the Twiml for my function
    stream_twiml = generate_stream_twiml(stream_url, "15")

    request_params = {
    "to" : "...",
    "from" : "...",
    "callback_url" : public_url + "/callstatus",
    "twiml" : stream_twiml
  }
    twilio_signature = validator.compute_signature(call_test_url, request_params)
    request_headers = {
    "X-Twilio-Signature" : twilio_signature
  }
    my_call_request = requests.post(call_test_url, headers=request_headers, data=request_params)
    print(my_call_request.content)

    return my_call_request
  
  else:
      print("No file created to retrieve public endpoint.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
call_request()


The second module is my server:
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_sock import Sock
from vosk import SetLogLevel
import time
import audioop
import base64
import json
import os
import vosk
import logging

port = 1234
file_path = "path-to-file-that-contains-ngrok-public-url"

app = Flask(__name__)
sock = Sock(app)
log = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
log.disabled = True
model = vosk.Model('my-model')

CL = '\x1b[0K'
BS = '\x08'

@app.route('/callstatus', methods=['POST'])
def get_call_status():
    from twilio_script import call_request
    call_status = request.form.get('CallStatus')
    call_sid = request.form.get('CallSID')
    print(f"Call status: {call_status}")
    if call_status == "busy":
        print("Callee busy. Calling again...")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        call_request()

    return call_status

@sock.route('/stream')
def stream(ws):
    """Receive and transcribe audio stream."""
    rec = vosk.KaldiRecognizer(model, 16000)
    while True:
        message = ws.receive()
        packet = json.loads(message)
        if packet['event'] == 'start':
            print('Streaming is starting')
        elif packet['event'] == 'stop':
            print('\nStreaming has stopped')
        elif packet['event'] == 'media':
            key_string = "..." # String to differentiate between automated responses
            audio = base64.b64decode(packet['media']['payload'])
            audio = audioop.ulaw2lin(audio, 2)
            audio = audioop.ratecv(audio, 2, 1, 8000, 16000, None)[0]
            if rec.AcceptWaveform(audio):
                r = json.loads(rec.Result())
                full_output = CL + r['text'] + ' '
                print("\n Transcription output: ", full_output)

                if key_string in full_output:
                   print("We're in, transferring call...")
                   # Logic to transfer call goes here
                   break
            else:
                r = json.loads(rec.PartialResult())
                partial_output = CL + r['partial'] + BS * len(r['partial'])
                print("\n Transcription output: ", partial_output)
                
                if key_string in partial_output:
                   print("We're in, transferring call...")
                   # Logic to transfer call goes here
                   break
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if os.path.exists(file_path):
        print("Deleting file...")
        os.remove(file_path)

    from pyngrok import ngrok
    public_url = ngrok.connect(port, bind_tls=True).public_url

    with open(file_path, "w") as file:
        file.write(public_url)

    app.run(port=port, debug=True, use_reloader=False)


The easiest way would be to use the call sid and update the call's TwiML to instruct the redirect (aka <Dial>) to your personal number:
call = client.calls('CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') \
             .update(twiml='<Response><Dial>415-123-4567</Dial></Response>')

print(call.to)


Thank you. How could I share the call_sid from my flask http route into the websocket connection?

It should be transmitted with the start event via the WS. So you don't need to forward it from the http route.
